SAS convert variable formats to a value
I have a SAS dataset which has formats applied to columns. So basically the value of the column is numeric and when I query the table it shows the value from the format. The problem I have is I have to export data to CSV and therefore I see original (numeric) values in CSV rather than formatted value.
I know I can convert column formats by using PUT statement.
id_formatted = PUT(id, NAME.);
I have done it like:
    data want;
    set have;
    id_fmt = put(id, NAME.);
    
    drop id;
    rename id_fmt=id;
    run;

Because I have quite a few tables with many columns with various formats I would like to find if there is an easy way to display format values instead of going one by one.
UPDATE:
For exporting to CSV I use:
proc export data=work.want
outfile= "~/test1.csv"
dbms=csv
replace;
run;

I just realized that I was using a different code that was rewriting datasets in between with format _all_; and therefore removing all formats.
After I tried again my export to CSV as above actually exports Format values and not original IDs as I mentioned.
Even though before I found that mistake, I have already taken an approach of using a macro that does a PUT on every column that uses format and then use export to CSV. I know this is not optimal, but it worked.
e.g.
%macro apply_col_format(p_lib=,p_table=,p_column=,p_format=);
DATA _tmp_table;
SET &p_lib..&p_table.;
&p_column._fmt_ = PUT(&p_column., &p_format..);
DROP &p_column.;
RENAME &p_column._fmt_=&p_column.;
RUN;

DATA &p_lib..&p_table.;
SET _tmp_table;
RUN;
%mend;

*setup if not setup prior;
%let outlib=mylib;

/* APPLY FORMATS ON COLUMNS using PUT statement so we get actual values in CSVs*/
proc datasets lib=&outlib. nolist nodetails nolist;
    contents data=_all_  out=work._format_cols NOPRINT ;
run;

PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE format_cols_filter AS 
SELECT libname as p_lib, memname as p_table, name as p_column, format as p_format, formatl 
FROM _format_cols 
WHERE format not in ('','DATE','$','DATETIME') and formatl = 0;

data _format_cols_run;
set format_cols_filter;
arg = CATS('%apply_col_format(p_lib=', p_lib
                        ,',p_table=', p_table
                        ,',p_column=', p_column
                        ,',p_format=', p_format,')');
call execute(arg);
run;


Welcome :-) How do you export the data to CSV?

Using: proc export data=work.want outfile= "~/test1.csv" dbms=csv replace; run;

How did you LOOK at the CSV file?  Because PROC EXPORT does write the FORMATTED values of the variables.

So there was a script creating CSV and when I looked at CSV it didn't have formatted values. But later when I checked the script again it was doing format _all_; somewhere in between and therefore I wasn't getting formatted values. Now that I have removed that piece of code it outputs formatted values.

Please show how you made the CSV file.
Did you have the formats attached to the variables before converting the dataset to the CSV file?  SAS will use the FORMATTED values when writing a CSV file.
Example:
2933   proc format ;
2934     value $sex 'M'='Male' 'F'='Female';
NOTE: Format $SEX has been output.
2935   run;

NOTE: PROCEDURE FORMAT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.04 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


2936
2937   data _null_;
2938     set sashelp.class (obs=3);
2939     file log dsd ;
2940     format sex $sex.;
2941     put (_all_) (+0);
2942   run;

Alfred,Male,14,69,112.5
Alice,Female,13,56.5,84
Barbara,Female,13,65.3,98


As mentioned above it was my error in not seeing in the script, a piece of code that removed formats. After removing that piece of code then the CSV contained all formatted values. Thank you for your help.

Use ODS destination CSV.
Example:
ods csv file='want.csv' ;
proc print noobs label data=have ;
run;
ods csv close ;

